# Joomla downgrade from 2.5 to 1.5 - Blank Page

Tags: php, .htaccess, joomla, configuration-files

i just made a webpage using joomla 2.5 and wamp server 2.5 too.

I got a hosting plan from a company that has Versión PHP:  5.1.6, so i realized that i was using a newer version of PHP and it could cause a problem (i had the page done at the moment)

So i decided to downgrade to wamp5_1.7.4 becuase is the one that has a PHP version that can be compatible with my hosting company php.

When i installed the new wamp and moved the files i went and imported the 2.5 DB to the "new" DB via phpmyadmin. it have me a error in the query, i googled it and fixed it. After that i wa sable to import the DB with no problems.

So everything is fine, i decided to go to localhost and it have me another error: need more memory, ok. Investigating i found that i should edit the htaccess or php.ini file with this: php_value memory_limit 64M and memory_limit = 16M respectevely. and **everything** worked perfectly in my localhost. also added ini_set('memory_limit', '32M'); to my configuration.php file

I went and did the same procedure but with my hosting company, and it just showed me a blank page. Decided to check the configuration.php file, and of course it was configured to try to work with a local server, so to get the one right i installed the 1.5 in the server (all worked) and kept the configuration.php file ... So i deleted the 1.5 DB, imported the 2.5 one (just like in my local pc) ad moved th 2.5 files into the server and changed the configuration.php for the 1.5 one.

I have done many things trying to ind the way to fix it, but it is still giving me a blank page. And what i dont want to do is just install the 1.5 joomla and have to redo everything from 0

Edit:
I added all the php error reporting and its not showing anything.. I right click on the page and click the option view page code, and it doesnt show.anything either...

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you pay for a years hosting upfront or something? Because if not it would be 1000 times easier to move to a decent host that isnt using a seriously outdated php version.

Comment: Lol, trust me, i am so mad about it because of the ridiculous PHP and plesk panel version, its real old, and drives me crazy. No i paid only 1 year for the service. But its not my personal webpage (i would have done that long ago) its for the company im working for.

Comment: OK, well i would still lobby fr better hosting, but if you do intend to go down the downgrade route, the 1st thing you need to do is enable error reporting so you know whats wrong. Add the following to whatever is the bootstrap file in joomla: `ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);` Then you wont get white pages, but instead usefull error messages

Comment: In which file should i add the suggested code lines?

Comment: Im afraid i have not looked at joomla for about 7 years, so i dont know the exact file. Probably there is a config.php or similar that is called for every page request.

Comment: no problem steve. I copied the code in configuration.php, php.ini and htaccess.txt, and its not showing anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than looking at the hosts server specs before purchasing, you purchased, and then decided to downgrade to 1.5 rather than move host? Word of advice, always look at what you are purchasing!

You **cannot** downgrade from Joomla 2.5 to 1.5 as there are drastic changes between the 2 versions, both files and database structure. The only thing you can do it create a new Joomla 1.5 installation, copy and paste your content over, then install Joomla 1.5 compatible versions of all 3rd party extensions you used

Comment: What errors are you getting on your live host? If you're getting a blank screen, then check the error logs

Comment: i will take your advice, and steve's and will move to a better hosting company.